# Git из директории в директорию

Tags: git

После перехода с SVN на Git появились проблемы с настройкой сервера деплоймента.

Все по порядку. У нас есть такая структура папок в бренче master:

```
trunk_old/
    ....
trunk/
    Тут все файлы сайта и статика
```

Мне нужно сделать pull только директории trunk со всеми файлами и субдиректориями внутри. Это отлично получается сделать с помощью команды:

```
git fetch origin master trunk
git checkout trunk
```

Но теперь папка trunk создается, собственно в папке www (там где создан git репозиторий) ну и получается что сайт доступен не по **site.ru/**, а по **site.ru/trunk/**. А нужно что бы все файлы из нужной нам директории скачивались в корень репозитория.

Как это исправить с помощью правильной комбинации git-команд? Есть идеи?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479960/git-checkout-to-a-specific-folder

Comment: так trunk в svn это просто текущая ветка разработки git, зачем вам вообще эту структуру повторять в git ? (ну и в конце концов, у вас же сайт, значит у него есть docroot, укажите его на директорию site.ru/trunk если уж так надо)

Answer (score 2):

Можно вот так

```
 git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter trunk/ -- --all
```